# Displayed string outputs differently in Android

Tags: android

I have some code that parses an html string and turns it into a regular string.

The input:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a
>   elementum nisl. Cras interdum velit non ex gravida dapibus. Donec
>   cursus tempor lacus eget finibus. Donec euismod enim vitae nibh
>   blandit,

Output on screen 2:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit=2E Vivamus a
>   elem= entum nisl=2E Cras interdum velit non ex gravida dapibus=2E
>   Donec cursus tempor lacus eget finibus=2E Donec euismod enim vitae
>   nibh blandit,

However on screen 1 the output matches the input. My question is what in my code could be causing this, I didn't write this whole app so there is a lot of code I would have to go through to find the bug so I am trying to narrow down what could be causing the difference in the two outputs.Also I really have no clue why elementum becomes elem= entum, I am guessing that is a line break issue?

Edit: Basically what would cause these two outputs to be different and how can I track it down.

Edit 2: Here is a secondary input output

Input

> Testing periods . then …  and now quotes “inside quotes” then ex ! @ # $ % ^ & >* ( ) - _ +  = \ | [] {} ; : ‘ “ , . / ? <> ` ~

Output

> Testing periods =2E then =E2=80=A6  and now quotes =E2=80=9Cinside >q=uotes=E2=80=9D then ex ! @ # $ % ^ & * ()-_+  =3D \|[]{}; =: >=E2=80=98 =E2=80=9C , =2E /? <>' ~

Other then the   screen 1 is the same as the input

Edit 3: Since I am guessing my parsing of HTML is causing some of the issue I will include that code since I know where to find it.

```
String bod = body.toString();


        String bod2 = cleanTagPerservingLineBreaks(bod);
        removeExtendedChars(bod2);
        String bod3 = bod2.replace("=2E", "\\.");
        return bod3;
    }

    public String cleanTagPerservingLineBreaks(String html) {
        String result = "";
        if (html == null)
            return html;
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
        document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings()
                .prettyPrint(false));// makes html() preserve linebreaks and
        // spacing
        document.select("br").append("\\n");
        document.select("p").prepend("\\n\\n");
        result = document.html().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
        result = Jsoup.clean(result, "", Whitelist.none(),
                new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
        return result;
    }

    public String removeExtendedChars(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", " ");
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? There is too much fluff in this post. Please simplify, possibly provide screenshots.

Comment: show the code you display text in each screens, and add some log to make sure those inputs is the same on 2 screens

Comment: I am not too sure of the usage and how it can be different on the two screens. It looks like you need to decode output2:

java.net.URLDecoder.decode(output2, "UTF-8");

Comment: @JoxTraex I shortened it a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: @Minhtdh I am trying to find that code and that is basically my question is what to look for when trying to debug this. All the gui stuff wasn't written by me an it's not well written at that....